# Understanding the behavior of electron two-beam systems | Plasma physics

Tags: thermodynamics, plasma-physics

I am studying the behavior of an electron beam going through plasma. Such particle beam is created by adding equal and opposing velocity drifts $v_0$ to the electron distribution  $$v = v_{th} \pm
 v_0$$

Where $v_{th}$ represents the Maxwellian distribution with characteristic thermal velocity
$v_{te}$

I ran the simulation twice, with the following parameters

grid_length $= 3.14$ (normalized size of spatial grid $k_pL$) $dt = 0.1$ (normalised timestep ($\omega_pdt$)), $\rho_0 = 1.0$ (background ion density), $v_{te} = 0.01$ (normalized thermal velocity ($v_{te}/c$) and $v_0=0.5$ [resulting in the first set of plots]

For the second run I used the same parameters but this time with $v_0 = 0.01 = v_{te}$ [resulting in the first set of plots].

OK now I would like to draw the attention to understanding the physics of the plots. Next I will go through a comparison of each plot.

- **v-x plot**. In the first set, $v$ is constant due to the existence of a clear drift $v_0 > v_{te}$. It seems that if $v_0 = 0.01 = v_{te}$, we just obtain free electrons instead of a beam (why?).
- **Electron density-x plot**. First consider that in the simulation I set the electric field to be zero. For the first set: it makes sense that the density remains constant given that we have a beam of particles. For the second set: as we are dealing with free particles, the density per unit of grid oscillates.
- **Velocity distribution**. For the first set: we have two peaks, due to $\pm v_0$. For the second set: we get a Maxwellian distribution, which makes perfect sense given that we are dealing with free electrons.
- **Energy-t plot:** We get no result for neither set, given that the initial normalized timestep is zero for both.
- **Energy-k plot:** I do not really understand why they are almost identical (only remarkable difference I see is the minimum showing up in the first plot)

So my two main doubts are: 1) why do we obtain free electrons when $v_0 = 0.01 = v_{te}$, 2) What can we understand from the energy-k plot comparison?

Please feel free to comment on the other comparisons.

[image]

..........................................

[image]

Comment: I don’t think $v$ denotes the distribution but the velocity. The distribution function is usually denoted with $f(v)$. Can you please double check the wording of your question?

Comment: This is a simple two-stream instability.  When $V_{Te}$ ~ $V_{oe}$, the two beams cannot NOT interact, which causes the scatter in your 2nd set of plots.  For the first set, you probably need to run it a  little longer to get the onset of an instability.